# Getting some part of String c#

Tags: c#, parsing

თანხის შეტანა ბარათი მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი VISA CLASSIC GE****************0082 GEL 
თანხის შეტანა შემნახველი მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი ჩემი სეიფი GE****************0018 GEL@
თანხის შეტანა ბარათი ცენტრალური ფილიალი MC STANDARD GE****************0006 USD კურსი - 2.5@

this is my strings kinda similar but its different always . I would like to get string from English Letter . in 1st option from "V" in second option from "G" in third option from "M" . easily to say when he sees english letter i want to get all the string from that point.

Comment: OK so you're saying that you have a load of non-Roman characters and you want to ditch them and just keep everything from the first Roman character?

Comment: You can always try to use regular expressions (may be available at `System.Text.RegularExpressions`).

Comment: @john yes thats what i am trying to do i have non-roman characters and want to get all the string from 1st roman character

Comment: what about something like : "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" in Regex ?

Comment: Im confused, do you want just  the credit card info?

Comment: Unclear question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex.  I added a '\n' to and of each line to look like code was read from a file.  You can use StreamReader instead of StringReader to read from a file.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = "[A-Z].*";

            string input =
                "თანხის შეტანა ბარათი მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი VISA CLASSIC GE****************0082 GEL\n" +
                "თანხის შეტანა შემნახველი მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი ჩემი სეიფი GE****************0018 GEL@\n" +
                "თანხის შეტანა ბარათი ცენტრალური ფილიალი MC STANDARD GE****************0006 USD კურსი - 2.5@\n";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string line = "";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(line, pattern).Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Never mind, looks like you fixed that